# Dead links in the "Stack Exchange 2011 Elections Begin" blog post

Tags: feature-request, blog, link-rot

[This](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-exchange-2011-elections-begin/) blog post contains links to http://se.awio.com/ which is now long time dead:

> [image]

Can those links be removed, probably with the whole related section? Can't see a reason to keep dead links around, people are likely still finding this blog post when searching so better keep it clean.

Comment: Well, they could just be updated to point to the new location of that page too.

Comment: @TimStone new location? I thought the person behind this left, didn't know there's a new location.

Comment: If I recall, [Dan Grossman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/280598/dan-grossman) was hosting it at that address, but the content was http://elections.stackexchange.com